# PHP multidimensional array - foreach loop showing last array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array as follow:-

```
$worksheet = array(
  'sheet 1' => array(
    '#1 sheet 1',
    ' #2 sheet 1',
    '#3 sheet 1'
  ),

  'sheet 2' => array(
    '#1 sheet 2',
    '#2 sheet 2'
  ),

  'sheet 3' => array(
    '#1 sheet 3',
    '#2 sheet 3'
  )
);
```

then I run PHP code as below:

```
foreach($worksheet as $ws=>$value)
  echo $ws.'<br/>';
{
  foreach($value as $sheet=>$ivalue)
  {
    echo $ivalue.'<br/>';
  }
}
```

Above code will generate only the last array like follow:

```
sheet 1,  sheet 2,  sheet 3,  #1 sheet 3,  #2 sheet 3
```

what had happen to my:

```
#1 sheet 1, #2 sheet 1, #3 sheet 1, #1 sheet 2, #2 sheet 2.
```

Comment: Try to clean up your indentation before asking.

Comment: Updated indentation to make the code more readable.  @FirstLast, please edit your question to move `echo $ws.'<br/>';` where it actually lives in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your syntax. `echo` is not inside the `{}`s as you intend.  Otherwise, PHP will assume that you just intend to do the echo, and won't realize you want to do an internal loop.

To fix:

```
foreach($worksheet as $ws=>$value)
{
     echo $ws.'<br/>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you did a mistake. The second and the third lines of your code are reversed. The code should be like this:

```
foreach($worksheet as $ws=>$value)
{
         echo $ws.'<br/>';
```

Thus, your code is looping with the external `foreach` through the echo and then, in a "section" enclosed by the brackets `{`, is doing another loop (the inner `foreach`).

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $ws.'<br/>'
```

should be inside the brackets